# Background not applying for video closed captions ::cue on Firefox and Safari on iOS Mobile

Tags: html, css, ios, html5-video, closed-captions

I am trying to style closed caption on HTML5 video player via `::cue` css selector like below. [codepen Link](https://codepen.io/krish4u/pen/dygRzyj)

```
::cue {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); /*Not working on iOS Mobile Firefox, Safari*/
  color: #463C40;
}
```

the background property works fine in chrome - desktop, firefox - desktop. but the same is not working on iOS mobile firefox and safari.

I tried to implement the background color via linear-gradient like below. But it adds a outline(looks like a border) [codepen link](https://codepen.io/krish4u/pen/PoyjmvQ)

```
::cue{
  color: #463C40;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8),rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
}
```

the background property is [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::cue#permitted_properties) for ::cue have verified it from MDN. Is there any way to make the iOS mobile browsers to render the background color.

Thanks in advance.

Status Update (Jan 2024) : No solution found so far for this issue, we have switched back to browsers default way of showing closed captions on its own.

Comment: The background Color is working on my iPhone Safari OK but I do see the border on the linear gradient version. What IOS version are you on?

Comment: @AHaworth I am validating on version 15 and 16.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try the below code:

***background: url("back.jpg") #033049;***
or you can try this too:
***html, body {background:url('images/back.jpg');}***

Comment: I haven't experienced this problem myself. Unfortunately, the question did not provide nearly enough context to identify the underlying problem so I can't confirm your answer would solve the problem.  But your answer is still a valid alternative approach.

Comment: This answer is for adding a background image and fallback as background color, But the scope of the question is to style ::cue on HTML5 video on safari and firefox on iOS